# Почему не работает метод save()?

Tags: php, yii2

У меня есть два метода в модели:

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {

        $this->password = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($this->password);

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
    {
        # Добавляем пользователю группу пользователя
        $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
        $user_group = $auth->getRole('user');
        $auth->assign($user_group, $this->id);
        parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
    }
```

Перед регистрацией генерируем пароль для пользователя. И устанавливается ему группа user после регистрации.

Сейчас возникла такая проблема, что при попытки обновить данные пользователя, к примеру имя.

```
$model = Users::findOne(['id'=>1]);
$model->name = 'New name';
$model->save();
```

$model->save() - возвращает false.
$model->validate() - возвращает false;
$model->getErrors() - возвращает пустой массив.

Вот сам процесс в работе изменения поля, я изменяю баланс:

```
//$user = Users::findOne(['id'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);
$user = Users::find()->where(['id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])->one();
        $user->balance = ($user->balance - $cost);
        
        if (!$order->save() || !$user->update()) {
            $response = ['code' => -99, 'text' => 'Произошла неизвестная ошибка, обратитесь в тех поддержку, код ошибки: -99'];
            $this->printAPI($response);
        } else {
            $response = ["code" => 5, "text" => "Заказ №" . $order->id . " успешно создан! ", 'balance' => $user->balance];
            $this->printAPI($response);
        }
```

Мне просто false возвращает и все, без каких либо ошибок. 
В модели в правилах есть balance тип стоит validator стоит double
В чем может быть проблема ? Почему не сохраняет, я грешу на методы after и berfore save, но я их пробовал закомментировать, все равно не сохраняет. 
Хоть бы блин ошибки вывел... Но ведь их нету

Comment: а в переменной ```model``` модель user есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в валидации либо поведении.

1. Валидатор не записывает ошибку.
   Отключите все Валидаторы и проверьте код на работоспособность. Если все ок, то по одному включайте валидаторы что бы выявить какой из них возвращяет false. Если такой найден то в нем, ищите почему нету записи ошибки в массив ошибок.
2. Проблема в поведении.
   Часто поведения используют что бы подготовить данные к выводу на фронте, пример: в БД поле `create_at` типа `int`, а в фронте нужен формат "d-m-Y H:i". Перебирайте подобным образом все поведения.

**Ультимативное решение:**
Настройте и используйте `xDebug`.